# Do Moogle Charms Increase XP Gained for Skills Such as Cooking?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Moogle Charms say that they increase experience gained, however they don't specify if that experience is only that which contributes to your character level or if it also applies to the equipped characters skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that the EXP bonus for sleeping in different places (hotel vs. camping outside) doesn't increase the EXP gained towards skills, it doesn't seem like the Moogle Charms' EXP gain increase would affect the skills progression, either.

Comment: They do not, technically, skills level with a "SP" rating. Its kind of hidden outside of the skill bar, but it isnt "exp", specifically.

Comment: Ah, I had missed that "SP" is a thing. Good to know!